# Powershell systeminfo execution time

Tags: powershell, execution-time

I have a PowerShell script to collect various types of information on the host system. One of the commands is `systeminfo`. It needs nearly 10 seconds to complete.

**Edit:**

I think the problem comes from the amount of installed hotfixes on the computer, which are displayed with `systeminfo`. Is there any way to run `systeminfo` without loading all the hotfix information?

Comment: I don't think this is a constructive question, nor it has anything to do with PowerShell.

Comment: Maybe I need to be more specific: I think the problem comes from the installed hotfixes on the computer, which are displayed with `systeminfo`. Is there any way to run `systeminfo` without loading all the hotfix information?

Comment: in this case, this question has nothing to do with PowerShell, and doesn't really belong to stackoverflow, more like serverfault...

Comment: systeminfo.exe is slow, and not part of PowerShell...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot not have hotfix information. See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb491007.aspx for the available parameters.

Comment: You could however use PowerShell CmdLets (and maybe WMI) to separately collect the information that systeminfo does..

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I'm new to Powershell and I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `Get-WmiObject` can help you to get the information you need. Check the following link describing different system information you can retrieve via `Get-WmiObject`.

[Get-WmiObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/getting-started/cookbooks/collecting-information-about-computers)